# Issue with rendering a particular JSON property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The `status` property on the JSON data below will not show on the table whenever I input new data at a particular index. As it seems, my code is only displaying the `status` properties of the data that was originally in the JSON but not the ones that get added. Posted below are the JSON and the codes for the add_data, add_button, and the table components.

JSON(I have kept the JSON short for obvious reasons but the other properties in each of the `grievance` and `services` keys are `serial_number`, `name`, `date`, `issue`, and `status` as you would see in the table that follows)

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "6",
                "grievance": [
                    {"status": "open"}
                ],
                "services": [
                    {"status": "pending"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "7",
                "grievance": [
                    {"status": "open"}
                ],
                "services": [
                    {"status": "closed"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "9",
                "grievance": [
                    {"status": "open"}
                ],
                "services": [
                    {"status": "pending"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "district": "Hooghly",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "10",
                "grievance": [
                    {"status": "pending"}
                ],
                "services": [
                    {"status": "pending"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "11",
                "grievance": [
                    {"status": "open"}
                ],
                "services": [
                    {"status": "closed"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "12",
                "grievance": [
                    {"status": "pending"}
                ],
                "services": [
                    {"status": "open"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`add_data.jsx`(This is the form for taking inputs. Again, to avoid this question from getting too lengthy, I have only shown the code that's taking the input for status. Just to add, the status gets selected from the dropdown.)

```
const AddDataScreen = () => {
    const [openState, setOpenState] = useState(false);
    const [stateDropdown, setStateDropdown] = useState('');

    const onStatusSelectValue = (value) => {
        setStateDropdown(value);
        setOpenState(!openState);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>Status</label>
                <div className="blockStatusDrop">
                    <div className="statusSelectDropdown">
                        <div className="statusSearchBox">
                            {!stateDropdown ? "Set Status" : stateDropdown}
                        </div>
                        <div className="searchStatusIcon" onClick={() => setOpenState(prev => !prev)}>
                            {openState ? <GoTriangleUp size={"22px"} /> : <IoMdArrowDropdown size={"30px"} />}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={openState ? "statusSelectedOption" : "statusOption"}>
                        <div onClick={() => onStatusSelectValue("open")}>Open</div>
                        <div onClick={() => onStatusSelectValue("pending")}>Pending</div>
                        <div onClick={() => onStatusSelectValue("closed")}>Closed</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="buttonContainer">
                <div className="submitButton">
                    <AddButton state={stateDropdown} id={`00${serviceRequestNumber.length + 1}`} type={typeDropDown} district={districtDropdown} ward={wardDropdown} name={name} issue={issue} description={description} ></AddButton>
                </div>
                <div className="resetButton" onClick={resetForm}>Reset</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddDataScreen;
```

`add_button.jsx`(This is the AddButton Component which facilitates the insertion of data at a particular index. The props named `district`, `ward` and `type` from the `AddDataScreen` component are used to find the index at which the data is to be inserted. Please note, that props.state is the `state` value and amazingly enough, when I console.log(props.state) to check if the value was selected from the previous component, it does show the selected option from the dropdown the screenshot for which is given below)

```
const AddButton = (props) => {

    const query = {               //The query parameters
        district: props.district,
        ward: props.ward,
        category: props.type
    }

    console.log(props.state)
    
    const insertData = {
        serial_number: props.id,
        name: props.name,
        date: new Date().toISOString(),
        issue: props.issue,
        description: props.description.split(/[,.]/),
        state: props.state
    };
    
    //This is where the filtering happens to find the index 
    const districtData = dummyData.find(value => value.district === query.district);

    const submitData = () => {
        //This is where the data is getting pushed
        if (districtData) {
            const wardData = districtData.ward_no.find(value => value.ward === query.ward);
            if (wardData) {
                wardData[query.category.toLowerCase()].push(insertData);
            }
        }
        console.log(dummyData);
    }

    return (
        <div className="submitAddButton" onClick={submitData}>Submit</div>
    );
}

export default AddButton;
```

[image]

In this screenshot, you can see that the status of the new data(i.e Bruno Fernandes) does have a value that says open which is exactly what was selected.

[image]

Now finally, when it comes to displaying this data on the table, this is the outcome. The status doesn't show.
[image]

table.jsx

```
const Table = (props) => {
    const data = [];
    const history = useHistory();

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data)

    useEffect(() => {
        setTableData(props.buttonValue)
    }, [props.buttonValue]);

    const tableDataPage = () => {
        history.push("/tableData")
    };

    return (
        <div className="tableDataList">
            {!tableData ? "" : <table className="serviceRequestList">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{ width: "5%" }}>Serial Number<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Name<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Date<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Issue<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Status<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                    </tr>
                    {tableData.map((value, key) => (
                        <tr key={key} onClick={tableDataPage}>
                            <td>{value.serial_number}</td>
                            <td>{value.name}</td>
                            <td>{value.date}</td>
                            <td>{value.issue}</td>
                            <td>{value.status}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AddButton**

Based on your screenshot, your dummyData should have the key as status, but in your insertData, you are using the state key. The issue might be with the key mismatch.

```js
const insertData = {
        serial_number: props.id,
        name: props.name,
        date: new Date().toISOString(),
        issue: props.issue,
        description: props.description.split(/[,.]/),
        status: props.state
};
```

Comment: I feel funny honestly.  I basically had the answer open in front of me all this time. Wish Stack Overflow had emojis for people to express their feeling. Thank You So Much.